# Character advancements with talents "(any X)"

Tags: character-advancement, wfrp-2e, wfrp

Question was asked to me as GM about advancing from **Apprentice Runesmith** to **Journeyman Runesmith**.

Apprentice has talent list containing one position: “Rune (any two...)”.
Journeyman has “Rune (any six)”.

From my understanding of advancement rules, following applies:

- Journeyman starts with **2** Rune talents, but can buy another **six**
- He can, however, finish his career by learning only **4** more, leaving another **2** Rune talents optional to learn

Is it proper interpretation of RAW? Or it should be just "*runesmith already has 2 talents of 'any six', so he can only learn 4 more*"?

I know there are only 18 "lesser" runes in the *Realms of Sorcery*, so learning 2+6+10+10 seems far-fetched here, but there are mentions of "*runesmiths learn runes from independent studies and **experimentations***", so I guess there is room for inventing new runes (if dwarf is given many years to do so).

It's especially important, because there is no advancement of **Master Rune** or **Rune** talents between *Master Runesmith* and *Runelord*. Both of these careers have **Rune (any ten)** and **Master Rune (any two)**, but it feels to me that *Runelord* should be able to master more Master Runes than "lesser" runesmiths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You increase your limit of options every new career

This ruling can be found on page 28 of the core book:

> Some careers give you options like "any two" or "any three" for skills and talents. if you already have enough skills and talents from the list, you don't need to buy new ones to finish the career, but you can at your option. A Master Wizard, for example, will already have two Lesser Magic talents from Journeyman Wizard careeer, so spending xp on more isn't required". However, the Master Wizard **could buy two new Lesser Magic talents if desired**".

On his example, the Master Wizard career gives you **two** options of Lesser Magic talents, the same as Journeyman Wizard.

So, if a character had the option to buy a talent 2 times, then, when he advances his career, he obtains the option to buy the talent 3 times. If he already bought the talent 2 times, he can now buy it *three additional times*, but he does not *need* to to advance to his next career. However, this character cannot buy the talents from his previous career, so he can only buy this talent 3 times on his current career.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'm using translated books (Polish versions) and in translated Core book there was no paragraph you quoted. I found pdf and checked English Core so yes, you are right. Thank you very much :)